# What does @V1 mean in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

There is a project that I need to maintain that talks to mysql via jdbc and there is an insert statement that looks like this:

```
loadStr.append("IGNORE INTO TABLE xxx.inventory (tn, @v1, @v2, @v3)");
```

What does the @v# mean?

Comment: `"IGNORE INTO"`? nice statement ;-) It's probably part of an `"INSERT IGNORE INTO"`, but I like it better the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @ symbol means it's a variable.

Comment: But that variable isn't being provided anywhere.  The code pretty much just does the query after that.